# Count the matched values in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to count the matched values in data like in (table1)

```
name    id  subject
maria   01  Math computer english
faro    02  Computer stat english
hina    03  Chemistry physics bio
```

The below query

```
Select *
from table1
where subject like ‘%english%’ or 
      subject like ‘%stat%’
```

returns first two rows :

But I also need to count the matched values like below output

```
count
1
2
0
```

(Because in the first row only one value matches, in the second row two matches and in third row there are no matches).

can i get that desired output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try summing `CASE` expressions which check each condition:

```
SELECT
    subject,
    CASE WHEN subject LIKE '%english%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN subject LIKE '%stat%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count
FROM 
    yourTable;
```

If you instead wanted to get a count of the number of words in each subject which did *not* match to one of the two keywords, you could try:

```
SELECT
    subject,
    LENGTH(subject) - LENGTH(REPLACE(subject, ' ', '')) + 1 -
    ( subject LIKE '%English%' ) - ( subject LIKE '%stat%' ) AS count
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you.... i get that. one more favor please. can i also count unmatched values like output count (2,1,3) (Because in the first row two values are not matching, in the second row one not matching and in third row there are no matching).

Comment: @taliafrasat Check my updated answer for a way of doing this.

Comment: yes.. but why are you adding +1..it gives output count(3,2,4)...but without +1 i get exactly same output count (2,1,3)

Comment: I am counting the length of the `subject` before and after removing all spaces.  Assuming the `subject` were one word, this difference would be zero, but since we know there is really _1_ word, we need to `+1` for the offset.

Comment: Can i also get the un-matched content or values also like column_name(math computer, computer, chemistry physics bio)?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, that is a much harder requirement.  If you really have a long term need for this, then consider storing each `subject` word in a separate record.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite validates conditions returning boolean values with `1` and `0` for `true` and `false` respectively, so you can do it like this:

```
select *,
  (subject like '%english%') 
  + 
  (subject like '%stat%') as count 
from table1
```

Comment: One more favor please. can i also count unmatched values like output count (2,1,3) (Because in the first row two values are not matching, in the second row one not matching and in third row there are no matching)